# Why this function overloading is not working?

Tags: c++, overloading

```
class CConfFile
{
    public:
        CConfFile(const std::string &FileName);
        ~CConfFile();
        ...
        std::string GetString(const std::string &Section, const std::string &Key);
        void GetString(const std::string &Section, const std::string &Key, char *Buffer, unsigned int BufferSize);
        ...
}

string CConfFile::GetString(const string &Section, const string &Key)
{
    return GetKeyValue(Section, Key);
}

void GetString(const string &Section, const string &Key, char *Buffer, unsigned int BufferSize)
{
    string Str = GetString(Section, Key);     // *** ERROR ***
    strncpy(Buffer, Str.c_str(), Str.size());
}
```

Why do I get an error `too few arguments to function ‘void GetString(const std::string&, const std::string&, char*, unsigned int)'` at the second function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `CConFile::GetString()` is, as the name suggest, a class member function, that is not accessible the way you call it in the second function. 
The other function you're declaring, `GetString()`, is a **global** one.

You just forgot to add `CConFile::` to the second function...

Answer (score 11):

You haven't scoped the second function with `CConfFile::`. It is being compiled as a free function, so the call to `GetString` resolves to itself (recursively), which requires four parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is because of not having a CConfFile instance to call that function, so it is assuming you are calling the other one.